# Linear Algebra - Quadratic Forms

Tags: linear-algebra

my first time here and it's about time I actually joined this site.
So my question is about Quadratic Forms, more specifically surfaces and related problems.

We have our quadratic form just in matrix form right away:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 3 & 2 \\
        3 & -4 & 3 \\
        2 & 3 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Assuming I did correctly, I found the eigenvalues to be -3, -1 and 2

And the corresponding eigenvectors to be (-1,0,1), (3,2,3) and (-1,0,-1) respectively and they are orthogonal to each other which of course creates an orthonormal basis.

Now I have to find the type of surface and the points closest to the origin and I'm not exactly sure how you go on about it.
Like how do you calculate c from this equation? Maybe I'm just insecure about how to do it.

$$
\Lambda_1(x_1')^2+\Lambda_2(x_2')^2+\Lambda_3(x_3')^2 = c
$$

According to the answer the surface is a Hyperboloid of two sheets and the closest points to the origin are +/-(3,2,3)

Comment: Your eigenvalues and eigenvectors are incorrect. If you multiply, for example, $(-1,0,1)$ by this matrix, you get $(1,0,-1)$, not $(3,0,-3)$. Also, the determinant of the matrix is 30, but the product of your eigenvalues is 6.

Comment: Yeah hehe I re-did it and I got the correct values too but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To find quadratic form when you have the matrix, all you need to do is to perform a couple of vector/matrix multiplications, i.e

$$Q(\vec{x}) = \vec{x}^T A \vec{x}$$

In your case, $$Q(x, y, z) = \left(\begin{matrix}x & y &z \end{matrix}\right) 
 \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 3 & 2 \\ 3 & -4 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \end{matrix}\right) 
 \left(\begin{matrix}x \\ y \\z \end{matrix}\right) 
$$

To find characteristic polynomial, we need to find determinant of matrix $\lambda I - A$. 
$$P(\lambda)=(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+4)-22\lambda-34$$ The roots of $P(\lambda)=0$ are $-6, -1, 5$. Thus, there is an orthogonal change of coordinates that will transform the original quadratic form into: $$-6x'^2-y'^2+5z'^2=c$$ Now you need to find the extreme points by setting two variables to zero and solving for the remaining variable. After you find these points, determine which one is the closest to the origin. Finally, you need to do reverse transformation from the new coordinate system to the old one.

Comment: Thanks but that wasn't really my question, I had the quadratic form since the beginning, I just wrote the matrix form of it directly to save space, my question is, once I have found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, how do I find the closest points to the origin?

Comment: I updated the answer, please take a look. It would also help to see the original quadratic form

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I re-calculated the eigenvalues again and I got the same as you now too, I made a sign mistake I guess. Another follow-up question, for 3 variables, do you always have to set 2 variables = 0 or does it depend on both the surface and the value of c? The Quadratic form was:  q(x) = x^2 - 4x^2 + x^2 + 6x_1x_2 + 4x_1x_3 + 6x_2x_3

Comment: afaik, we always set two variables to 0 if we have all 3 variables as these points are points of intersections of axes and the surface. Of course drawing the surface will help to identify which point is closer to the origin. The value of $c$ should be given.

Comment: Sorry my bad, c = 110, I don't know why I keep leaving it out, last question which is similar, do you set any 2 eigenvalues = 0 or do you know already which ones to put = 0?, It seems in this case we put eigenvalue 1 and 2 = 0 making the third the closest eigenvector but maybe it is that simple I'm not sure.

Comment: It depends on signs and values of eigenvalues and the value of $c$ (btw, number of minuses is the number of sheets if $c \gt 0$ ), obviously in this case the closest two points will lie on the third axis. In general, the largest positive eigenvalue will give you the closest points if $c \gt 0$

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I wanted to know, now I understand a lot better, the only thing now is to more easily see what type of surface you get and I should be able to solve most of these type of problems :)

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues and eigenvectors that you computed are incorrect, but they do have the correct signature (pattern of signs), so we’ll work with that.

By convention, the matrix $A$ contains the coefficients of the implicit equation $\mathbf x^T A \mathbf x=1$ of the quadric surface. If the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$, then there’s an orthonormal basis—consisting of orthogonal unit eigenvectors of $A$—in which the equation of the surface is of the form $$\lambda_1 x_1^2+\lambda_2 x_2^2 + \lambda_3 x_3^2=1. \tag1$$ The type of surface is determined by the pattern of signs of the eigenvalues. For this quadric, the pattern is $+--$, which means that the equation is of the form $${x_1^2\over a^2}-{x_2^2 \over b^2}-{x_3^2\over c^2}=1. \tag2$$ This is the equation of a hyperboloid of two sheets.

For a quadric centered at the origin, the nearest and farthest points from the origin lie on the principal axes. Comparing equations (1) and (2), we can see that the half-axis lengths are equal to $\sqrt{|1/\lambda_i|}$. For a hyperboloid of two sheets, there are nearest points to the origin—its vertices—but no farthest points. The vertices lie on the axis that corresponds to the positive eigenvalue. This eigenvalue is actually $5$, with corresponding unit eigenvector $\frac1{\sqrt{22}} (3,2,3)$, so the nearest points to the origin are $\pm\frac1{\sqrt{110}}(3,2,3)$. Note that these points are *not* $\pm(3,2,3)$, although they do lie along the line with that direction vector. For $(3,2,3)$ to be a vertex, the equation would have to have $110$ on the right-hand side instead of $1$, but there’s nothing in your question that would lead us to make this choice a priori.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the right side should have 110, I just somehow forgot to put that in for some reason but again thanks because this is exactly what they do not explain at all or clearly in any book...